# syntax error near unexpected token `do'

Tags: bash, shell, batch-file

I am trying to convert a .bat file into .sh file here is my lines of code

```
#!/bin/sh
./setenv.sh
export _LIBJARS=for i in [$XYZ_HOME$/lib/*.jar];do source $XYZ_HOME$/bin/append.bat i
export CLASSPATH=$ANT_HOME$/lib/ant.jar;$_LIBJARS$$ANT_HOME$/bin/ant -buildfile $XYZ_HOME$/build.xml $1 $2 $3 $4
```

After writing these line I wrote `chmod 755 ./build.sh`
then I wrote `./build.sh test-deploy`

I am getting the following error:

```
./build.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
./build.sh: line 3: `export _LIBJARS=for i in [$XYZ_HOME$/lib/*.jar];do source $XYZ_HOME$/bin/append.bat i'
```

My .Bat file is like

```
call setenv.bat

set _LIBJARS=
for %%i in (%XYZ_HOME%\lib\*.jar) do call %XYZ_HOME%\bin\append.bat %%i

set CLASSPATH=%ANT_HOME%\lib\ant.jar;%_LIBJARS%

%ANT_HOME%\bin\ant -buildfile %XYZ_HOME%\build.xml %1 %2 %3 %4
```

Or any tutorial to understand the lines of code or related to shell and bash file please suggest me.

Comment: maybe `export _LIBJARS=$(for ....)`. I cannot understand what do you want to do in the 3rd line... It seems you want to put inside _LIBJARS the output of that bat files.

Comment: @DavidWallace Sir if I omit the semicolon I get the error as follows

./build.sh: line 3: export: `[$/lib/*.jar]do': not a valid identifier
./build.sh: line 3: export: `$/bin/append.bat': not a valid identifier

Comment: **1** Shell variables are not written with a `$` at the end. **2** `source [...].bat` looks like asking for trouble, **3** @Hastur is probably right, and also add a `done`. **4** That for loop is wrong in so many ways, maybe you ought to start with a shell/Bash tutorial.

Comment: Why did you need to `source` your bat file? It's not enough to execute it? When you `source` a script is somehow as if you write its code in the point of the script where you source it. @Biffen spots as trouble this point. We do not know how append.bat behaves and if it needs to start in a new shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash Shell and Batch are two completely different programming languages with their own syntax and the way they work.

For example:

```
call setenv.bat
```

Will run `setenv.bat` in your script and return control to your current script. However:

```
./setenv.sh
```

Will spawn a new shell, set the environment in that shell, and then return to the parent shell where those environment variables are not set. To do the equivalent in shell, you must *source* in `setenv.sh`:

```
. ./setenv.sh
```

OR

```
source ./setenv.sh
```

The first is compatible to all *Bourne Style* shells. The last is more readable, but may not be compatible with different shells.

```
set _LIBJARS=
for %%i in (%XYZ_HOME%\lib\*.jar) do call %XYZ_HOME%\bin\append.bat %%i

set CLASSPATH=%ANT_HOME%\lib\ant.jar;%_LIBJARS%
```

In Shell, you can do this:

```
export CLASSPATH=%ANT_HOME%\lib\ant.jar
for jar in ($XYZ_HOME/lib/*.jar)
do
    CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:$jar"
done
```

Remember, this is only taking place INSIDE this shell script. Unlike Batch, it's not affect the parent shell, so using `$CLASSPATH` is fine.

Finally:

```
$ANT_HOME/bin/ant -buildfile $XYZ_HOME/build.xml $*
```

The `$*` will work no matter how many target are passed.

Comment: Thanks It's working but need to add export keyword before `CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:$jar" `

Comment: You're right. I should have looked a bit more carefully at the batch script. Usually, when you build `$CLASSPATH`, you use it in the command that follows. I now see that you're not.

Answer (score 0):

This might be how you want it to do:

```
#!/bin/sh

. ./setenv.sh  # Must 'source' or else you won't get the values.
_LIBJARS=

for I in "$XYZ_HOME/lib/"*.jar; do
    . "$XYZ_HOME/bin/append.sh" "$I"
done

export CLASSPATH=$ANT_HOME/lib/ant.jar:$_LIBJARS
"$ANT_HOME/bin/ant" -buildfile "$XYZ_HOME/build.xml" "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4"  ## Or perhaps it should simply be "$@"?
```

Comment: Wouldn't the `*.jar` need to be placed before the closing `"` or does it work either way?

Comment: Inside quotes, the `*` is treated literally, not as a glob.

Comment: @chepner: Right, thanks. I thought it was only single quotes that had that effect – I must have misremembered it.